# Calculating the Square Root using the Babylon Algorithm

Tags: java

For my assignment, I am supposed to use a 'Tolerance Flag'. Yet, I was able to complete the task with what I have so far. What does my teacher mean by tolerance flag?

```
Use a tolerance flag and make your variables a member of the double class.
const double TOLERANCE = 5e-8;
double x = 2.0;
```

_

My Work:

```
public class Sqrt_of_Two {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final double TOLERANCE = 5e-8;
        double x = 2;

        do{
            x = (x + 2/x) / 2;

            System.out.println(x);
        }while( Math.ceil(x*x) > 2);


    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1.5
1.4166666666666665
1.4142156862745097
1.4142135623746899
1.414213562373095
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's an online assignment. I haven't got a reply yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it means something like:

```
while(Math.abs(x*x - 2) > TOLERANCE);
```

which outputs:

```
1.5
1.4166666666666665
1.4142156862745097
1.4142135623746899
```